# Can't insert value of many-to-many field into other table in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-class-based-views

I am using django 1.8. I am trying to insert a value into database using CreateView in django. I can insert data into database. The problem is to insert value of one field (many-to-many). The field is to insert another table. I will explain briefly below

**models.py**

```
 class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    first_name = models.ManytoManyField(Model2)

 class Model2(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
```

**forms.py**

```
 class sampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.TextInput()
    address = forms.TextInput()
    first_name = forms.TextInput()
```

**views.py**

```
 class Create(CreateView):
    model = Model1
    form = sampleForm
    def form_valid(form):
      form.save()
      return super(Create,self).form_valid(form)
```

When i try to insert value into database, name and address are inserted successfully into one table. first_name field need to insert into another table. But it's not inserted. Can anyone help me to do this.

Comment: what's `sampleForm`?

Comment: sampleForm means class name which is in  forms.py file..

Comment: why do you not show it? problem may be related to that.

Comment: now i have posted it...

Comment: your expectations are wrong: the many-to-many field allows you to relate tables. It does not create partial copies of one row inserted in a table into the related table. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

in your view file you can do it by this code i guess

```
 class Create(CreateView):
    model = Model1
    form = sampleForm
    def form_valid(form):
      form.save(commit=false)
      form.save()
      form.save_m2m()
      return super(Create,self).form_valid(form)
```